# Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred, when deploying project on Google App Engune

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have been trying to deploy my project on Google Cloud SDK since yesterday and have been getting the same error over and over.

My app.yaml file looks like:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 2.3
  disk_size_gb: 10

network:
  session_affinity: true
  name: custom-project

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: custom-project:europe-west3:custom
```

I use this command to deploy:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

And I get this error:

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.                                                                                                                                                                                      
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred.
```

Comment: Your deployment logs should have the answer though they are voluminous so it is kind of like looking for a needle in a haystack.  My guess is you are exceeding memory.

Comment: May we see some of the code? Do you have permissions on the project? And, like @gaefan suggested, have you checked the logs?